# Creating a simple extension in chrome that randomizes the letters of every word in a page

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

Essentially what I am trying to do, is recreating this extension:

https://github.com/viktorsec/bumpercar-candysnatch

But instead of only replacing certain words I want to replace all words on a website by their own letters in a different randomized order. This is the what I came up with:

```
var elements = document.getElementsByTagName('*');

for (var i = 0; i < elements.length; i++) {
    var element = elements[i];

    for (var j = 0; j < element.childNodes.length; j++) {
        var node = element.childNodes[j];

        if (node.nodeType === 3) {
            var text = node.nodeValue;
            n = text.length;
            for (var h = n - 1; h > 0; h--) {
                var p = Math.floor(Math.random() * (h + 1));
                var tmp = text[h]
                text[p] = tmp;
                }
                element.replaceChild(document.createTextNode(text), node);
            }
        }
    }
```

But it doesnt work at all. Is an extension like this even possible?

Comment: Hi, start trying something more simple like to anagram a single word. Forget extension for now.

Comment: Thats not really helpful

Comment: Hi LionIsLoose. I think Robbi is possibly exaggerating how much help his comment was by a _tiny_ bit.

To make it more likely that you get quality answers I would suggest you explain in what way your solution doesn't work; does it throw any errors? Does it just do nothing? Have you managed to get anything to work at all? Also, maybe try creating a minimal example, which is I think what Robbi meant to say.